# They look like tiny black ants but they're not I find them only in my son's toy box

Tags: entomology, species-distribution

I find these only in my son's toy box not in the kitchen or not around food I have bleached all my son's toys and they still come back they are not crawling along the wall or anywhere else in the room or any other toy box in the room there is no food in the toy box as I've cleaned it thoroughly but I don't know what they are they seem to live for a little bit and then just die they only stay in the bottom of his toy box can you help me figure this out or how to get rid of them[image]
They are tiny and black as you can see

Comment: Unless your toys include grain of some sort, it's not likely these are actually living on the toys. I'd check your food stocks more carefully, especially rice and grains. Do you have neighbors?

Comment: Check for a bag of corn, rice, wheat, cereal, etc. That's the source. They will spread through the whole house given enough time. They're small enough to crawl "under" carpet surface and so move about great distances before being found. Are pretty harmless to everything but your food other than being a "gross" infestation. Mechanical removal + sealing available food necessary to slowly eliminate.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as it has three legs to a side, which are visible towards its right side (zoom in as far as you can) relative to the rest of the picture, appears to have a protruding set of mouthparts, and has a body that's visually divided into two parts, I'm *tentatively* going to call that a [weevil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weevil).

As Bryan Krause pointed out: check any food you might have in your house for them. Weevils like eating things.

Alternatively, it might be a member of [a weevil family that feeds on dead wood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthribidae). Is the toy box made of wood?

Comment: Unlikely to be Anthribidae ("family that feeds on dead wood") due to wrong habitat, size, morphology, etc..... Also, all animals "like eating things"

Comment: @theforestecologist More specifically, weevils like eating things that people would prefer uneaten.